# Looking for a Chinese movie or anime with easy dialogues

Tags: resources

I'm looking for a movie with both English and Chinese subtitles (important).
 On my blog http://bymyselflearning.blogspot.fr you can see that I've already collected a few ones.

Basic idea: displaying the Chinese movie, a sketchpad and a dictionary together, side by side, can really help the learner if the dialogues are rather simple.

Comment: Chinese SE is not primarily designed for such requests. There are many subtitle sharing websites where you can search for movies and check what subtitles they have. Use the search engine of your choice.

Comment: Looking for movies with subtitles is not a problem...I'm just searching one with very easy dialogue...Ok that's true that I can search by myself...eh eh...I was expecting that kind of answer.

Comment: I keep in mind that the name of the community is "Chinese language"...and in "Chinese language", there is the word "language" of course...I perfectly understand !

Comment: Hero (英雄) 2002. You got both subtitles (english, chinese and others) at opensubtitles dot org. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend "[小蝌蚪找妈妈](https://youtu.be/Cpspc7it3SY)". It's short with a meaningful story for kids. The conversation is simple and slow.

Comment: The oldish style makes this animation even sweeter !

Comment: ♡ I propose capitalising on the full potential of this single video. Something really valuable could be drawn from it...eh eh

Comment: http://bymyselflearning.blogspot.fr/2015/05/index_25.html   ...We are a team. Thanks a lot, Madwyn. I did it !

Comment: Well done! I'm really happy to see that you like this old film.